# Azure App Service + Docker Autodeploy?

Tags: azure, docker, continuous-integration, azure-web-app-service

I have setup an Azure App Service to host a docker container.  This is all running fine -- pointing at a private Docker repository/image, using the `latest` tag.

I would like to be able to publish a new Dockage image from my CI server to the Docker repository under the `latest` tag and somehow trigger the App Service to pick up that there is a change of the `latest` image.

It seems I can trigger the change by modifying an Application Setting on the App Service and saving it -- but this does not seem like the correct way to handle it.

Is there a best practise for this kind of deployment?

Answer (score 1):

In the properties section of the web app you'll find a `DEPLOYMENT TRIGGER URL`.

This URL should point to the `/deploy` endpoint. Remove that part and use the `/docker/hook` endpoint.
Your URL should look something like this: `https://xxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook`

If you `POST` to that URL with empty body it will trigger a deployment using the latest docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Currently they are working on a solution for this scenario but as stated in [their FAQ about Web App on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-faq) either modifying the application settings or restarting the web app is the only way of triggering the change.